# Como inverter um número positivo para negativo e vice versa no C#?

Tags: c#, .net, matemática, operadores

Como faço para que o número digitado pelo usuário, seja ele positivo ou negativo se inverta?

```
using System;

namespace POOTeste
{
    class Program2
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int numero;
            Console.Write("Digite um número positivo ou negativo: ");
            numero = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write($"O valor inverso é {numero}");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Você pode multiplicar por **-1** para inverter o valor dele, e verificar se é negativo com `< 0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colocando o sinal de negativo (-) igual na matemática. Além disso parece que ainda não aprendeu pegar um número digitado corretamente, conforme eu já te respondi antes (pode dar uma mensagem de erro mais significativa ou fazer um laço para pedir de novo se a pessoa digitou algo errado). Então o correto seria:

```
using static System.Console;

namespace POOTeste {
    public class Program2 {
        public static int Main() {
            Write("Digite um número positivo ou negativo: ");
            if (!int.TryParse(ReadLine(), out var numero)) return 1;
            Write($"O valor inverso é {-numero}");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/NWkqck). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QOfrnq). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/InvertNumber.cs).